# Differential equation similar to "Heat equation" without $u(l,0)=0$ boundary condition

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations, heat-equation

I'm supposed to solve this problem

$$ \begin{align}\frac{\partial u }{\partial t} &= c^2 \frac{\partial ^2u }{\partial x^2}\\\text{ so that :} \\x&>0\\ t&>0 \\
u(x,0)&=f(x)\\
u(0,t)&=0\end{align}$$

It is similar to heat equation but I couldn't figure out how to solve it without $u(l,t)=0$ boundary condition.

Could someone help me, please?

Comment: Use the separation of variables method , see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_variables

Comment: This is still the heat equation, btw. Only with different boundary/initial conditions with respect to what you may have seen in the past.

Comment: Your domain in semi infinite in space, so use the Laplace transform.

Comment: Another standard trick for the semi-infinite Dirichlet problem is the method of odd extensions. Extend $f(x)$ to an odd function on the entire real line, and then solve the heat equation on the entire real line $-\infty < x < \infty.$ The solution remains odd for all time and so $u(0,t)=0$.

Comment: @E.H.E Separation of variables does not work so well on unbounded domains.

Answer (score 0):

Of course use separation of variables:

Let $u(x,t)=X(x)T(t)$ ,

Then $X(x)T'(t)=c^2X''(x)T(t)$

$\dfrac{T'(t)}{c^2T(t)}=\dfrac{X''(x)}{X(x)}=-s^2$

$\begin{cases}\dfrac{T'(t)}{c^2T(t)}=-s^2\\X''(x)+s^2X(x)=0\end{cases}$

$\begin{cases}T(t)=c_3(s)e^{-c^2ts^2}\\X(x)=\begin{cases}c_1(s)\sin xs+c_2(s)\cos xs&\text{when}~s\neq0\\c_1x+c_2&\text{when}~s=0\end{cases}\end{cases}$

$\therefore u(x,t)=\int_0^\infty C_1(s)e^{-c^2ts^2}\sin xs~ds+\int_0^\infty C_2(s)e^{-c^2ts^2}\cos xs~ds$

$u(0,t)=0$ :

$\int_0^\infty C_2(s)e^{-c^2ts^2}~ds=0$

$C_2(s)=0$

$\therefore u(x,t)=\int_0^\infty C_1(s)e^{-c^2ts^2}\sin xs~ds$

$u(x,0)=f(x)$ :

$\int_0^\infty C_1(s)\sin xs~ds=f(x)$

$\mathcal{F}_{s,s\to x}\{C_1(s)\}=f(x)$

$C_1(s)=\mathcal{F}^{-1}_{s,x\to s}\{f(x)\}$

$\therefore u(x,t)=\int_0^\infty\mathcal{F}^{-1}_{s,x\to s}\{f(x)\}e^{-c^2ts^2}\sin xs~ds$